# Issues installing packages on windows 10 pro with chocolatey, I cannot find the installed packages on my PC anywhere

Tags: windows, package, chocolatey, package-management

**Problem: After installing packages on windows 10 pro with chocolatey I cannot find them installed on my pc**

After resetting my windows dev environment again I decided it would be time to use a package manager in win akin to linux apt-get to save on setup time in the future.

I came across chocolate and it sounded like exactly what I was asking for. 
I created a small packages.config and ran

`choco install ./packages.config`

After the process completed it prompted that all packages installed successfully.
Yet the installed packages do not appear to exist anywhere on my filesystem.

- Programs do not appear in C:/Program Files or (x86).
- When I type their names eg: putty into run they come up not found.
- There are a few scattered installer .exe files appearing in the chocolatey folder C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin but thats all.

**Am I doing it wrong? Is chocolatey only useful for acquiring installer files? Seems spectacularly unuseful in that case?**

**Can recommend an alternative package manager for windows.**

Here is my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="vscode" />
  <package id="docker-desktop" />
  <package id="whatsapp" />
  <package id="vlc" />
  <package id="paint.net" />
  <package id="spotify" />
  <package id="bitnami-xampp" />
  <package id="zoom" />
  <package id="steam" />
  <package id="7zip" />
  <package id="handbrake" />
  <package id="itunes" />
  <package id="notepadplusplus" />
  <package id="winscp" />
  <package id="putty" />
</packages>
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you share a gist/log of the installation procedure? what is the output if you run the command again? have you had a look in C:/programdata/chocolatey/lib - is there a folder for each of the packages you wanted to install?